Existe uma possibilidade de usar as classes do Tailwind em propriedades no react Native?
Estou utilizando o NativeWind no meu projeto React Native, mas gostaria também de utilizar as classes do Tailwind em algumas propriedades de componentes do React Native.
Por exemplo:
<TextInput className='flex-1 p-2' placeholder='Adicionar' placeholderTextColor="bg-gray-200"/>

Nesse caso não é possivel aplicar esse estilo de cor na propriedade PlaceholderTextColor
Você tem alguma ideia de como contornar essa situação? e pode me ajudar???
